# Getting the query string out of an rdflib prepared query

Tags: python, rdflib

How do I recover the original string from an `rdflib` preparedQuery.

In other words,

```py
query_string = "select ?s {?s ?p ?o.}"
q = prepareQuery(query_string)
```

I would like to run some function against `q` to recover the `query_string`.

Comment: It may not be possible to do this, as the parameters in a prepared statement are usually bound in the database itself, and not in the calling app code (Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found how to do this.  Simply:

```
q._original_args
```

returns a tuple of the original arguments used to prepare the query.